# nginx "redirected you too many times."

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx file

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.website.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.website.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

When trying to connect to my website, I get a too many redirect error. How can I fix this? For reference, I am following [this](https://lengstorf.com/code/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/) SSL guide.

Edit: Using Cloudflare, full SSL

Comment: Do you have other `server` block(s) listening on port 80?

Comment: @PhilipTzou No that is the entire file

Comment: Try use Chrome Developer Tools -> Network (Check "Preserve log") to trace the redirection target.

Comment: Wait you are using Cloudflare? It probably proxied traffic to your 80 port but not 443 port. Check your Cloudflare configuration too.

Comment: `default~` looks like a backup file left behind by an editor.

Comment: @PhilipTzou The networking panel shows continous tries for the api.website.com resulting in a `301` status. As for cloudflare, how can I check that configuration?

Comment: @user82395214 https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-3-SSL-options You need at least use the Full SSL option.